# Opengl texture with black edge

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glfw

I'm trying to figure out the right way to render a single texture in OpenGL and I used the LearnOpengGL tutorial. at the first, I code it by myself, but I got the different result with the one tutorial shows. below is my result with a black edge:

[image]

which is different from the tutorial one:

[image]

then I checked my code again and again, It doesn't work. Finally I copy the tutorial code all, and run it, it still have the black edge. I have no idea what is happening.

Below is the tutorial code:

```
// load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture1, texture2;
    // texture 1
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); 
     // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
    // The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/container.jpg").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
    // texture 2
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    data = stbi_load(FileSystem::getPath("resources/textures/awesomeface.png").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        // note that the awesomeface.png has transparency and thus an alpha channel, so make sure to tell OpenGL the data type is of GL_RGBA
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
// tell opengl for each sampler to which texture unit it belongs to (only has to be done once)
    ourShader.use(); // don't forget to activate/use the shader before setting uniforms!
    // either set it manually like so:
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "texture1"), 0);
    // or set it via the texture class
    ourShader.setInt("texture2", 1);
// render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // bind textures on corresponding texture units
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

        // render container
        ourShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

Comment: Might help to show the fragment shader.

Comment: Did you enable blending ?

Comment: glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable( GL_BLEND );

Comment: It works after I enable blending, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable Transparency we need to enable Blending

This is how blending is enabled.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
```

Comment: VS:  glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); Which one is better?

Comment: @Aaron Lee glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); is for premultiplied alpha

Comment: glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); is for straight alpha